# Apply CSS stylesheet to all elements but one

Tags: css

I have several grids (kendo grids). This have their common style with their hover effect. I want to prevent this hover effect for only one grid, named mygrid.

Tryed this with no success:

```
 .k-grid tr:hover :not(#mygrid)
 {
  color:White;
  background-color:#90B5DA;
 }
```

Comment: `.k-grid:not(#mygrid) tr:hover`

Answer (score 3):

The correct usage of `not` is attached to another selector. For example:

```
.k-grid:not(#mygrid)
```

Will select all elements with the class `k-grid` except if the element has an id of `mygrid`

So what you want is this:

```
.k-grid:not(#mygrid) tr:hover
```

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#negation

Comment: `#not` is not supported in `ie6-8` (predictably) which might be an issue.

Comment: @Ross the OP included the CSS3 tag, so I didn't take non-CSS3 browsers into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

The already suggested use of `:not()` is correct.  For wider support, you may consider doing something like this, where the :hover state of `#mygrid` is the same as the "off" state:

```
.k-grid tr,
#mygrid tr:hover /* Add this rule to the "off" state */
{
  color:Grey;
  background-color:#333;
}

.k-grid tr:hover
{
  color:White;
  background-color:#90B5DA;
}
```